# Inkscape PPA not installing updates?

Tags: ppa, inkscape

I have inkscape 0.48 installed and I'm trying to install inkscape 0.91 
on the site they provide me with these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

When I enter the 1st line of commands it comes up with this

```
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 The Inkscape Stable PPA is intended to provide the current supported release of Inkscape.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.Pph6xzLEzv --trustdb-name /etc/apt//trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv 22C4850146603F3DB0ED00479DA4BD18B9A06DE3
gpg: requesting key B9A06DE3 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key B9A06DE3: "Launchpad PPA for Inkscape Developers" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

What do I need to change so that the pc accepts the ppa?

Comment: Your key has been accepted already.

Comment: Put the output of `apt-get update` as an edit.  The full output.  And tell us what OS you are using.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Debian Wheez?  Nice =) and OT here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments made by the OP on other answers (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633350/need-help-with-adding-ppa/633368?noredirect=1#comment902734_633357)), we see a PPA 404 stating the PPAs 404 on Debian Wheezy checks to try and find Debian packages.

That suggests the original poster is using Debian, not Ubuntu.

PPAs from Launchpad will only support Ubuntu, and there is no Debian support currently.  Don't try and mix Launchpad / Ubuntu PPAs and Debian.

You will need a Debian solution (check Debian Unstable for packages possibly) or you will have to build from source.

Answer (score 3):

As [@ThomasW.](https://askubuntu.com/a/633368/367165) said

> we see a PPA 404 stating the PPAs 404 on Debian Wheezy checks to try
>   and find Debian packages.

Debian Wheezy is off-topic here.

***Therefore*** the following solutions only works with Ubuntu systems

---

---

There is no problem. The PPA is added and the public key is imported.

Update the package information

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install `inkscape` with

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

Or upgrade your system if inkscape is already installed

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for plasma: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
my inkscape is still on version 0.48 after all the commands and need to install version 0.91

Comment: As I wrote: `sudo apt-get update` and than `sudo apt-get upgrade `. What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"

Comment: @DewaldEsterhuysen you are trying to mix an Ubuntu PPA with Debian based on the error you posted (404). PPAs are for Ubuntu Only not Debian. –  Thomas W.